# How to use Token and Identity Authorization on resource?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, token, jwt

I have a WEB Api that uses User accounts for registration etc and also Tokens.
Now I want all the end points to be secured using both Token (JWT bearer) and Identity. So a user cant only have a valid Token but he must also be logged in. 
When I use `[Authorize(Policy = "Bearer")]` I get Token authorisation and when I used `[Authorize]` I get identity authorisation, how can I combine both? I would I assume I can do [Authorize(Policy = "Bearer, Identity")] (Based on the Roles logic) but I get an error ofcourse that the policy doesnt exist.
Is there a way to implement this?

Repo: https://github.com/drakoumel/DatacircleAPI

Answer (score 2):

> When I use [Authorize(Policy = "Bearer")] I get Token authorisation and when I used [Authorize] I get identity authorisation, how can I combine both? [sic]

Set the `ActiveAuthenticationSchemes` property. It takes a comma separated list of scheme names. Here is an example that activates the cookie middleware that Identity uses and the bearer (token) middleware.

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer, Identity.Application")]
```

Both the bearer and the cookie middleware will run and have a chance to create and append an identity for the current user.

Remarks:

You can activate whatever authentication schemes you need. The default scheme names are in the `Identity` and `Authentication` namespaces. E.g.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
    .JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme // "Bearer"

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
    .IdentityCookieOptions.ApplicationCookie // "Identity.Application"

...
```

See also:

- [Limiting Identity by Scheme](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme.html#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute)
- [JwtBearerDefaults](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerDefaults.cs)
- [IdentityCookieOptions](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityCookieOptions.cs)

Comment: Hmm I applied the line and now although the token is invalid (lifetime invalid) it proceeds normally and lets the user access the resource because he is logged in. Shouldnt it require both authentications to pass? 

This is my controller (getUser()) https://github.com/drakoumel/DatacircleAPI/blob/master/Controllers/AccountController.cs
And my startup.cs https://github.com/drakoumel/DatacircleAPI/blob/master/Startup.cs

Comment: So I get 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware[7]
      Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired.
And 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[3]
      HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Identity.Application.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

Comment: Based on documentation it says that both policies will have a change to populate the User, is it possible to enforce that both must pass?

Comment: @Drakoumel Let me see if I understand correctly. You would like to enforce both that the user has a token and that the user has a Cookie. Is that right?

Comment: yes. The thing is I need a secure application, and I cant have someone stealing the users token but not the cookie and using it.

Comment: @Drakoumel That is an unusual enough of a use case, that you will probably need to write a custom authorization policy. If I understand correctly, your apps user will log in to your app, and your app will issue both a cookie and an access token? Is that right?

Comment: Hmm ok, I would expect the framework to handle that but anyway. Thanks for the help, but sorry I wont be able to mark your answer as accepted :(

Comment: @Drakoumel Do you understand why it is an unusual use case? If the request can use the cookie, then just use the cookie. If the request cannot use a cookie (because of XSRF mitigation), then use the token. Using both is not supported for a reason.

Comment: I assumed that the combination of both would increase the security. Of course not thinking about mobile

Comment: @Drakoumel It wouldn't increase the security. Rather, it might decrease security as you managed issuing both Cookies and Tokens to the same client.